# perl how to print out a hash with multiple keys?

Tags: perl, hash, printing

i'm setting my hash in my function as

```
$hash{$loginId}{$month}=$hash{$loginId}{$month}+$time1;
```

and I can print the value in one spot as

```
print "$hash{maclawty796}{Sep}\n"; #just some name and date in the text file i imported
```

But I want to print out all the values. 
When i use

```
print "@{[%hash]}\n";
```

I get a bunch of weird results and what looks like memory addresses. How can i print out the loginId's Months and times?

Here's the full code if you need it

```
#
#  adapted from regex9.pl
#

$file ='timelog.txt';
open(INFO, $file) or die("Could not open  file.");


use strict;

my ($loginId, $month, $time1, $time2, $pts, $line, $time1T, $time2T);
my %hash=();


while  (<INFO>)
{
$line=$_;
#assignment of Login ID's
if( ($loginId) = /([a-y]*(\d|\w)*)/ ){
printf("%-15s", $loginId);
}

if( ($month) = /((Jan)|(Fed)|(Mar)|(Apr)|(May)|(Jun)|(Jul)|(Aug)|(Sep)|(Oct)|(Nov)|(Dec))/ ){
printf("%-5s", $month);
}

if(($time1, $time1T, $time2,$time2T)= /(\d\d):(\d\d)\s-\s(\d\d):(\d\d)/ ){
#print($time1, " ", $time1T, " ", $time2," ", $time2T,"\n"); #for testing
$time1=($time2*60+$time2T)-($time1*60+$time1T);
printf ("%-5s minutes\n" ,$time1);
}

$hash{$loginId}{$month}=$hash{$loginId}{$month}+$time1;
print "hash $hash{$loginId}{$month}\n";

}

print "@{[%hash]}\n";
print "$hash{maclawty796}{Sep}\n";
```

Comment: maclawty796          pts/1        10.1.28.122      Mon Oct 24 09:18 - 09:20  is like what's in my text file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values in `%hash` are references to other hashes. If you want to print the keys and values of those hashes, you'll have to instruct Perl to do so.

```
for my $loginId (keys(%hash)) {
   for my $month (keys(%{ $hash{$loginID} })) {
      print("$loginID $month $hash{$loginID}{$month}\n");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A hash can't have *multiple keys*. A hash only has a single level of keys, but the values of those keys can point to other hashes.

You have a hash called `%hash` that is keyed by `$loginId`. The values in this hash point to other *hashes* (each value is a completely separate hash) that are all keyed by `$month`. It's an important point to understand.

I find that I can help myself remember this by using the `->` operator. This reminds me I'm talking about *references* and not merely other keys.

For example, instead of writing this:

```
$hash{$loginId}{$month} = $hash{$loginId}{$month} + $time1;
```

I would have write this:

```
$hash{$loginId}->{$month} = $hash{$loginId}->{$month} + $time1;
```

It's not much, but it's a good reminder that `$month` are keys to a *hash reference* and I need to dereference that hash before I can see its values.

Let's take a simple loop that prints out `%hash`:

```
for my $loginId ( sort keys %hash ) {
    print qq(\$hash{$loginId} = "$hash{$loginId}"\n";
}
```

This will print out something like this:

```
$hash{bob} = "HASH(0x7f8e3b804ee8)"
$hash{david} = "HASH(0x...)"
$hash{sue} = "HASH(0x...)"
```

The `HASH{0x...)` are addresses to a hash reference. I need to *dereference* that hash to get the values:

```
for my $loginId ( sort keys %hash ) {
    my %months = %{ $hash{$loginId) };  # Dereferencing the hash;
}
```

Now, that I've dereferenced the hash, I can print out the months for each user:

```
for my $loginId ( sort keys %hash ) {
    my %months = %{ $hash{$loginId) };
    for my $month ( sort keys %months ) {
        print qq(\$hash{$loginId}->{$month} = ) . $hash{$loginId}->{$month} . "\n";
    }
}
```

By the way, there's no reason I couldn't combine the referencing with the inner for loop:

```
for my $loginId ( sort keys %hash ) {
    for my $month ( sort keys %{ $hash{$loginId) } ) {
        print qq(\$hash{$loginId}->{$month} = ) . $hash{$loginId}->{$month} . "\n";
    }
}
```

It looks like you were trying for a quick dump of all of your data. To do that, you can use the [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) module:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);  # Better way to print than print

use Data::Dumper;

....
say Dumper \%hash;  #Prints out the entire data structure.
```